# Interacting with icons through TABing

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery form window with mutliple objects that can be interacted with, buttons, text and finally the "X" icon.

```
    $('#cancel-feedback, #feedback-dialogs .icon-close, #feedbackCloseAfter').click(function (e) {
    closeDialog();
});
```

What I do not understand is why when I TAB through the objects to the "#cancel-feedback" (which is a button) and hit enter key the window closes but when I repeat the same process for the icon it does not.

Clicking with the mouse cursor works fine for both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the default behavior for a button is submit considered by some browsers specially IE. If you want to avoid this behavior make sure the button type is set explicitly:

For example

```
<button type="button">
```

[Working example](http://www.bootply.com/9Unwjs1AYY)

Comment: what If i want icon to close this form using the enter key as well?

Comment: In this case you have different options. Either to wrap the icon inside a button tag and explicitly set the type="Submit". Or you can have the icon tag with type="Submit". This should work.

Comment: Icon can not have a submit type as I do not want to submit the form when user wants to X out of the form (there are validations in check to ensure data is correct when submitting which are triggered if the type=submit). Other buttons that close the window have a button type and not submit. Also the icon is already wrapped in the button tag                 <button class="dialog-close" aria-label="close" href="#" type="button">
                    <span class="icon icon-close" id="FeedbackCloseIcon">x</span>
                </button>

Comment: @Michal Right!. Then in this case you only need to add an ENTER key event listener to your icon using JQuery. I updated the working example to demo this as well.